# Windows 8.1 taskbar preview issue

Tags: windows-8, taskbar, windows-8-preview

I was using windows 8 with my previous computer, and I didn't have this problems.

When I minimised videos preview seems to freeze, but not minimised its working;

[image]

I could see a preview of the game when I minimised them.

Now I can't see game previews anymore.

When I press <kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd>, it previously did not minimise the game.

Now, when I press <kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd>, the game minimises and there are no previews, only a grey or black preview window.

[image]

Comment: You do understand this behavior depends on the program itself right?  A program has to designed to act in a certain way when its minimized.  The problem you describe isn't actually a problem.

Comment: but like I said, I didn't have this problems with my previous computer. all games had previews and minimised videos could whathed from preview.

Comment: Which Windows 8 variant did u installed in that PC?

Comment: There are several reasons this could have changed.  Your display drivers could make a huge different.  You don't indicate if DOTA2 had this capability in the past or not.  Doesn't change the fact this is entirely up to the program to support or not support.

Comment: @Pankaj windows 8 single language same as the current and previous computer. btw both the same model, asus g750jh. just current comp have 32gb ram and larger hdd. display drivers and hardware same.